# initiative static property with env variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, class, static-methods

I created a class that extends from another class. First I defined a static property for it and called it in the whole class with "self::$baseURL". It was Ok.

```
class AccountCall extends APICall
{

    public static $baseURL = "https://example.com/api";


    public static function getBaseURL()
    {
        return self::$baseURL;
    }

}
```

in other files I use it like this:

```
AccountCall::getBaseURL();
```

Now I want to read this static value from the ENV file, and I don't want to change "AccountCall::getBaseURL();" in whole project, but I get an error. Help me please.

```
 public static $baseURL = (string) env('ACCOUNT_URL') .'/api/';
```

Comment: Don't use `env()` directly, create a [Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration) and use `config(...)`

Comment: "_but I get an error_" Would really help us help you if we knew what that error was

Comment: "message": "Constant expression contains invalid operations", this is my error. @brombeer